# 1 px line issue in native storyboard tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image: *enter image description here*]

Hello All,

Please help me in resolving this issue. I am facing the of 1 px gap in Tabbar in swift.It has four tabbar items and gap is coming after third tabbaritem(as you can see in picture). It is only here for iphone 6 plus. It is working perfectly in all other devices. I have tested , it is not the issue of image becuase I have already removed all the images from tabbaritems.
Your support is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance!